# Cross account s3 bucket sync using lambda(boto script)

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I need to sync up s3 buckets which are in different accounts.For that I create 2-buckets with bucket policy and Lambda function with iam policy and s3 event trigger.

I tried through CLI.Can any one help to write bot script to sync buckets

I am trying below code in lambda-

```
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

def sync_command(command):
    command_list = command.split(' ')

    try:
        logger.info("Running shell command: \"{}\"".format(command))
        result = subprocess.run(command_list, stdout=subprocess.PIPE);
        logger.info("Command output:\n---\n{}\n---".format(result.stdout.decode('UTF-8')))
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("Exception: {}".format(e))
        return False

    return True

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    logger.info(event);
    SOURCE_BUCKET = os.environ['source']
    print('SOURCE_BUCKET:', SOURCE_BUCKET)
    TARGET_BUCKET = os.environ['target']
    print('TARGET_BUCKET:', TARGET_BUCKET)

    sync_command("aws s3 sync s3://source-bucket/ s3://destination-bucket/")
```

but this is showing error *Exception: **[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'aws': 'aws***

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53517519/sync-two-buckets-through-boto3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sync two buckets through boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53517519/sync-two-buckets-through-boto3)

Answer (score 0):

I have did this using bob script , here is the code

```
import subprocess
import logging
import boto3

def check(bucket, key):
    s3client = boto3.client("s3")
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

    copy_source = {
          'Bucket': bucket,
          'Key': key
        }

    print("key",key)
    bucket = s3.Bucket('target_bucket')
    bucket.copy(copy_source,key)


def lambda_handler(event, context):
   ev = event["Records"]
   bucketName = ev[0]["s3"]["bucket"]["name"]
   keyName = ev[0]["s3"]["object"]["key"]
   check(bucketName,keyName)
```

working fine in lambda.