# What is the best approach to sync data from AWS 3 bucket to Azure Data Lake Gen 2

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3, aws-cli, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

Currently, I download csv files from AWS S3 to my local computer using:
`aws s3 sync s3://<cloud_source> c:/<local_destination> --profile aws_profile`. Now, I would like to use the same process to sync the files from AWS to Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 (**one-way sync**) on a daily basis. [*Note: I only have read/download permissions for the S3 data source.*]

I thought about 5 potential paths to solving this problem:

1. Use AWS CLI commands within Azure. *I'm not entirely sure how to do that without running an Azure VM. Also, I would like to have my AWS profile credentials persist?*
2. Use Python's `subprocess` library to run AWS CLI commands. I run into similar issues as option 1, namely a) maintaining a persistent install of AWS CLI, b) passing AWS profile credentials, and c) running without an Azure VM.
3. Use Python's [Boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html) library to access AWS services. In the past, it appears that Boto3 didn't support the AWS `sync` command. So, developers like @raydel-miranda developed their own. [*see [Sync two buckets through boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53517519/sync-two-buckets-through-boto3)*]. However, it now appears that there is a `DataSync` class for Boto3. [*see [DataSync | Boto3 Docs 1.17.27 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/datasync.html)*]. Would I still need to run this in an Azure VM or could I use Azure Data Factory?
4. Use Azure Data Factory to copy data from AWS S3 bucket. [see [Copy data from Amazon Simple Storage Service by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-amazon-simple-storage-service)] My concern would be that I would want to sync rather than copy. I believe Azure Data Factory has functionality to check if a file already exists, but what if the file has been deleted from AWS S3 data source?
5. Use [Azure Data Science Virtual Machine](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/virtual-machines/data-science-virtual-machines/) to: a) install the AWS CLI, 2) create my AWS profile to store the access credentials, and 3) run the `aws s3 sync...` command.

Any tips, suggestions, or ideas on automating this process are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Adding one more to the list :)
6. Please do also look into Azcopy option . https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-s3?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json

I am not aware of any tool which helps in syncing the data , more or less all will do the copy , I think you will have to implement that . Couple of quick thoughts .
#3 ) You can run this from a batch service . You can initate that from Azure data factory . Also since are talking about Python , you can also run that from Azure data bricks .

#4) ADF does not have any sync logic for the files to be deleted. We can implement that using the getMetadat activity . https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I will look into Azcopy, python with batch service, and Azure Databricks as potential solutions.

Answer (score 0):

AzReplciate is another option - especially for very large containers https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure/azreplicate/azreplicate/

Comment: Thanks. I will look into AzReplicate sample application.