# How can I transfer objects in buckets between two aws accounts with python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, aws-cli

I need to transfer all objects of all buckets, with the same folders and buckets structures, from an aws account to another aws account.
I've been doing it with this code through aws cli, one bucket at a time:

```
aws s3 sync s3://SOURCE-BUCKET-NAME s3://DESTINATION-BUCKET-NAME --no-verify-ssl
```

Can I do it with python for all objects of all buckets?

Answer (score 1):

The **AWS CLI** actually *is* a Python program. It includes multi-threading to copy multiple objects simultaneously, so it will likely be much more efficient than the equivalent Python program you can make yourself.

You can tweak some settings that might help: [AWS CLI S3 Configuration — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/s3-config.html)

There is no option to copy "all buckets" -- you would still need to sync/copy one bucket at a time.

Another approach would be to use **S3 Bucket Replication**, where AWS will replicate the buckets for you. This now works on *existing* objects. See: [Replicating existing objects between S3 buckets | AWS Storage Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/replicating-existing-objects-between-s3-buckets/)

Or, you could use **S3 Batch Operations**, which can take a manifest (a listing of objects) as input and then copy those objects to a desired destination. See: [Performing large-scale batch operations on Amazon S3 objects - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/batch-ops.html)

Answer (score 0):

`aws s3 sync` is a high level functionality not available in AWS SDKs such as `boto3`. You have to implement it yourself on top of `boto3` or search though many available code snippets that already implement that, such as [python - Sync two buckets through boto3 - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53517519/sync-two-buckets-through-boto3).