# copying files from one folder inside AWS bucket to another if the folder name matches using either AWS glue or lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I have 2 AWS buckets staging and destination both have the same number of subfolders let's assume 3.
So staging as 3 named a, b, c and destination have 3 a, b, c. Now i want to copy files from 3 subfolders a, b, c to destination a, b, and c which is present in another bucket only when the name matches ie a to a, b to b, c to c using AWS glue or AWS lambda. Also, the file inside this subfolder a, b, and c can be of any type.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a solution like this in lambda using python;
[Sync two buckets through boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53517519/sync-two-buckets-through-boto3)

You could use the cli. Check the examples at the bottom of the page.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html

You could also set up s3 batch replication from the console.
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/02/amazon-s3-batch-replication-synchronizes-existing-data-between-buckets/