# Run multiple AWS sync command in parallel to copy data from multiple source s3 to multiple destination s3

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, parallel-processing, aws-cli

I want to copy data from A bucket to M bucket, B bucket to N bucket and so on. To speed up the process I am running the sync command in parallel like this

```
source_buckets=(A B C D E F)
destination_buckets=(M N O P Q R)
parallel -j 6 "aws s3 sync s3://{1}/$release_version/ s3://{2}/" ::: "${source_buckets[@]}" ::: "${destination_buckets[@]}"
```

but with this command data from all buckets (A,B,C,D,E,F) is going to each bucket of destination. Can someone please help me to fix it?

Also, any alternative way to speed up the cp/sync process?

Answer (score 2):

You are using gnu parallel here which is probably trying to do what it is intended to, but not what you want.

I did a quick test and confirmed this without aws cli -

```
parallel echo ::: a b c ::: d e f
```

is doing the same thing -

```
a d
a e
a f
b d
b e
b f
c d
c e
c f
```

So there is `--link` option to match arrays:

```
parallel --link echo ::: a b c ::: d e f

a d
b e
c f
```

Regarding alternative ways - boto3 is the library behind AWS CLI, and you can use all power of python to do all kinds of things with it - see e.g. [Sync two buckets through boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53517519/sync-two-buckets-through-boto3)

Comment: For this particular use-case, I'd recommend the AWS CLI `sync` command since it can copy objects in parallel, which is much harder to accomplish when coding it yourself in Python. Good discovery about `--link` however!